# How do I use Spring Bean Builder with Spock outside of Grails environment?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spock

I'd like to test (using Spock) my Groovy code outside of Grails so I'm trying to set up a similar testing environment. I'm aware that there's a Spock extension for Spring support but I think it does not support Bean Builder syntax, only XML, which I'd like to avoid as much as I can. I've also been looking for a way to create custom Spock extensions but the documentation seem non-existent yet ("coming soon"). With JUnit, I can just create a `TestRunner` to inject the test with objects.

Comment: If you work with Spring 4 you could use http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html#groovy-bean-definition-dsl

Comment: I'm really more interested in how I could integrate that with my Spock Specifications by automatically injecting/autowiring the beans I define using the Bean Builder DSL.

Comment: More details would help, but have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-ctx-management-groovy, which should work as-is using spock-spring.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I think this brings me closer to what I'd like to achieve. To be honest, I'm not exactly sure how things should "look" like because there are different ways it can be approached. The idea I have in mind originally is to be able to wire beans by name... but anything that makes testing more convenient is fine with me. I wonder if there's an annotation similar to `@ContextConfig` that just takes the Groovy class name instead of the file location.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Groovy-based bean definition files are passed to Spring in source form, hence that's also what the TestContext framework supports.

Comment: Yeah, I actually had problems with that fact. I even had to rename the Groovy script because it got added to the classpath as a class, and not a resource.